# after quitting VIM editor I am not able to see the original screen contents that were present before entering vim

Tags: vim, text, text-editor

I want to see the original contents of screen after quitting vim 
as they were before opening a file , as of not my file quits but the original display is not there

THanks

Answer (score 4):

The feature of returning screen contents after running a full screen application vs, leaving the contents there, is not specific to vi, but to your terminal emulator. The feature you want to turn on to return to the previous text is often known as 'altscreen'. If you are using xterm as your terminal emulator, this behaviour is default. However if you are running GNU Screen inside of an xterm (or other terminal), you need to add the line

```
altscreen on
```

to your ~/.screenrc file. Other terminals that support this feature will have other mechanisms to turn it on and off.

Comment: I am using xterm , i dont have .screen file but i created one 
and written altscreen on but this does not help its the same

Comment: The file is .screenrc (not .screen), but that would only be relevant if you are using GNU Screen inside of xterm

Comment: ya but i am not using GNU screen in xterm , so there was no file

Answer (score 1):

Instead of quitting, you can put vim into the background by typing control-z. This restores the previous screen, but leaves you the editor running 'stopped' with the current file. To get vim back, enter the command
`fg %1` at the shell prompt. This brings vim back to the foreground again - at least assuming you only have one stopped job. The command `jobs` will give you a list of stopped jobs, which you can access by number.

So the work sequence becomes edit, save, control-z, compile, test, fg...

This works on linux, and Mac OS X - YMMV on other Unix variants.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xterm, then see `:help xterm-screens`, or ... read that anyway as it describes that your problem should be related to some `terminfo` setting - probably.

HTH